# Drupal and JSONAPI: filtering using "OR" doesn't seem to work

Tags: drupal, json-api

I have an "activity" node bundle which has a "practice" field, referencing a node of type "practice".

Using JSONAPI, I am trying to get the list of activity nodes which either:

- have no practice reference

  OR
- reference a specific practice node

Here is my JSONAPI query:

```
jsonapi/node/activity?
&filter[or-group][group][conjunction]=OR

&filter[filter1][condition][path]=field_practice
&filter[filter1][condition][operator]=IS%20NULL
&filter[filter1][condition][memberOf]=or-group

&filter[filter2][condition][path]=field_practice.id
&filter[filter2][condition][value]={some_id}
&filter[filter2][condition][memberOf]=or-group
```

I have an OR group, and then two filters in that group. However this doesn't work, it only returns nodes that fullfill the second filter (referencing a specific practice).

If I remove the second filter, then the first filter works fine.

If I remove the first filter, then the second filter works fine.

If I keep both, only the second filter if taken into account.

I am at a bit of a loss...

Comment: Strange.. Maybe the default operator fallback (`=`) is not applied correctly within a condition group. Did you try to be explicit (adding `&filter[filter2][condition][operator]=%3D`) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the suggestion. Yes, I've tried it and got the same result.

Comment: Anything in the logs ? It sounds like a bug.. I suggest you post this on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ and maybe open an issue at https://www.drupal.org/

Comment: does your filter1 group work on its own?